# I need to find the event ID of an android emulator

Tags: python, android, adb

I'm working on an emulator and control it though the module ppadb. The swipes not being precise enough, i found a script to use sendevent but to do so i need the "event id".

```
self.device.shell(f'sendevent /dev/input/event{self.eventId} {event}')
```

There is a shell command named getevent to be able to view it but i have no clue on how to write that in python. I would like the getevent result to be printed in the pycharm console.

Would you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `getevent` in a shell once and find out the device name and use that in your Python script to do the `sendevent` commands. Or you can use the `self.device.shell` command in Python to do it as well. To find out the name of the device you can run this command in an `adb shell` session:

```
getevent -pl 2>&1 | sed -n '/^add/{h}/ABS_MT_TOUCH/{x;s/[^/]*//p}'
```

Now it will return something like `/dev/input/event0` and you can use that with the command you already have to send events to that specific device.

If the `adb` command is not working in your terminal you can navigate to the `platform-tools` folder in your Android SDK folder and run it from there (in my case, my emulator was event1):
[image]

Comment: device.shell("getevent -pl 2>&1 | sed -n '/^add/{h}/ABS_MT_TOUCH/{x;s/[^/]*//p}'")

That was the syntax i used in python using ppadb to get a similar result. Got event6 in my case witch seems bounded to "User Input" as name description for the device.

Thanks a lot for your help